# How can I put my Invoke-Command results in a comma-delimited string

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

How can I get the results of `Invoke-Command` into a comma-delimited string

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $manyComputers -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
   hostname
}
```

expected output:

`"server1,server2"`

Comment: `-Join ','` may be an option. But I'd actually ask, why you need it in this ununsual particular format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-join` in Windows PowerShell 5.1:

```bash
$result = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $manyComputers -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
}) -join ','
```

In PowerShell 7+ you can use `Join-String`, much nicer syntax:

```bash
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $manyComputers -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
} | Join-String -Separator ','
```